# Augmented reality to measure - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image-processing, augmented-reality

This is my first time working on Augmented Reality topic. I am about to develop an application which uses augmented reality to recognise and measure the n number of objects in my room. Something like in the attached image. I need to identify each edges and corners and have to do some vast math calculation for the measurement. I am pretty sure that it cant be achieved only through iOS SDK, I need to use some external library/SDKs. I need some scanner SDK which does the real time image recognition.

[image]

I came across [Qualcomm's Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com), [Realitycap](http://www.realitycap.com), [metaIO](http://www.metaio.com). My dilemma is, a developer who worked in product and business based iOS application can do this image recognition stuff? An iOS developer does not have that awesome experience in image processing. Can anyone suggest me some cool stuff to come over? Suggest some ideas also, it will help me a lot.

Comment: It is not clear what specific question is being asked here or what a useful answer would look like.

Comment: Simply to say, how can I kickstart to develop an iOS app which uses augmented reality for measurement(recognise the objects via camera and measure them)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [metaio sdk](http://www.metaio.com/) to scan different objects. You can create as many object models in  `unity3D` and have in database. The above sdk helps you to do in 3D scanning and many more features.

Comment: Is there a way to export the models created using unity to my Xcode?

Comment: Actually there will be a sdk of metaio in which you have to import model of unity3d in that project. File type .vbx and many more is supported. You can try sample of metaio.

Comment: What you suggested is right. MetaIO provides such API. But I have not used unity3D before. So, I have adopted to use Structure Sensor - http://structure.io which gives me exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a possibility to use OpenCV

API can be found at: http://opencv.org